# JSoup java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException

Tags: jsoup

When trying to parse a Link, I see the following exception in the log file.

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: uft-8
at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:524)
at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:87)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:481) org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:149)
```

Not sure why utf-8 would be unsupported.

Comment: Please post your code and (if possible) url. Only with an exception it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsoup supports UTF-8, of course. However the URL you are hitting is returning "uft-8". I don't know what that is and neither does your JVM, which defines which character sets are supported. Whomever configured that URL has made a typo.

If this is a URL that you know and need to revisit, you could use jsoup.connection.execute, and munge the response encoding header to "UTF-8" before you run parse(), and set the encoding to UTF-8 explicitly.